# Windows-10 Home: random crash with black, non-illuminated screen

Tags: windows-10, crash

Updated/edited: 20230425 011000\Eastern.  Please see Addendum-01 (below).

**Updated/edited:** 20230424 054400\Eastern. Added display specifications that were mistakenly left out of the original post. See "Device Specifications:", near the bottom.

The description\details below have taken place in at least two differing ways:

a) Using the bare-bones ISO provided by and downloaded from Microsoft to a Usb drive. Post install, 'Event Viewer' will always hang/freeze while using its search function.

b) Not to be associated or confused with the ill-behavior of the 'Event Viewer', the random OS crashing seems to begin after *all* updates, both Microsoft and OEM have been applied. Post update runs of:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, then  `sfc /scannow` will *sometimes* find and repair corrupt files, but never after any of the described crashes below, has sfc /scannow found anything corrupt. This is why I began browsing 'Event Viewer'.

---

1. Regardless if a user is active with the user-interface or if the system has one or two user-applications running, with the OS otherwise being idle, the OS will randomly crash --leaving the user with a black, non-illuminated display, yet the hardware remains powered-on. At this point holding the power button, until the box shuts-down; is the only way to recover.

With case #1, while using 'Events Viewer' to get a clue, MMC will freeze, causing the user to perform a 'Task Manager | End Task'. After restarting and using the 'Event Viewers' search-function, the freeze will repeat itself.

To get the following data, I stopped using 'Event Viewers' search, then sorted the output by the 'Level' column header; with focus on the 'Critical' level.

2. Other times, not as frequent, the same machine will randomly generate a BSOD
3. I've noticed one cbs.log and numerous CbsPersist_yyyymmddhhmmss.log files. What key-word(s) should I search for to find any clues to my issue\s?

What is the best way to provide the excerpts from both the Events-Viewer and the Cbs log files without blowing up this thread but, also allowing access to the files in a way --not break any external links to the evidence for future reference. I don't use cloud storage.

-Cbs logs are as large as 36,000\KB.
-Event Viewer files, which is preferred, evtx or csv?

---

**Addendum-01**
The image below is from the 'Reliability Monitor', --all entries are 'Critical'. This output gives a clue to a possible hardware issue; something Event-Viewer is not, or does not display. I continue to struggle at finding a clue about 'which' hardware is the possible cause, or is Win-10 off-the-rails. I also note that, not always during the same time-frame will there be a 'hardware' error and a 'kernel Power' (Shutdown) entry. Again, Windows is not providing end-user friendly data.

[image: Windows-10, Reliability Monitor (Report)]

The following text-output are the details associated with the first (top) entry from the 'Reliability Monitors' report. I don't have the experience to read the Hex output.

Source
Windows

Summary
Hardware error

Date
‎4/‎21/‎2023 11:31 AM

Status
Not reported

Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   144
Parameter 1:    3003
Parameter 2:    ffff910bc39256b0
Parameter 3:    40010002
Parameter 4:    0
OS version: 10_0_19045
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    768_1
OS Version: 10.0.19045.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1033

---

This next text-output from the 'Reliability Monitor' is either just before the crash, or after the subsequent reboot.

Source
Windows

Summary
Shut down unexpectedly

Date
‎4/‎10/‎2023 8:40 PM

Status
Not reported

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
Code:   124
Parameter 1:    0
Parameter 2:    ffffd88667b17028
Parameter 3:    bc002800
Parameter 4:    c0135
OS version: 10_0_19045
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    768_1
OS Version: 10.0.19045.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1033

Does anyone have additional thoughts on this?
**End 'Addendum-01'**

---

Device Specifications:
Device name Life
Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics            2.90 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.4 GB usable)
Device ID   N/A
Product ID  N/A
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Display(s):
Name    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
Adapter Type    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, NVIDIA compatible
Adapter Description NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

Name    AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
Adapter Type    AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x1636), Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. compatible

---

Windows Specifications:
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎3/‎26/‎2023
OS build    19045.2846
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Respectfully

Comment: Only onboard GPU? What happens if you swap out the SSD/HDD?

Comment: @Gantendo -- I'm not sure what you mean, when you ask "Only onboard GPU?" 2) I have no indication of any SSD errors which would prompt me to --randomly throw money at a new storage device. 3) I have data from 'event Viewer' and CBS log files. I've previously asked a question about both, which I'm still waiting on a reply. Hopefully after the community reviews that [not yet submitted] data, we'll be able to address these issues intelligently; without guessing.

Comment: It sounds like the event logs get damaged which can be the cause of the freezes when you try to use event viewer. 
So in order to diagnose that swapping out the hdd/sdd (or booting from a live USB) can help isolate the problem to that specific hdd/sdd. But ok, you don't have one. Have you tried reading the event viewer logs via powershell to see if they can be read? https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-check-event-logs-with-powershell-get-eventlog/

Comment: 1.    Stop the Event Log service, either through the Services console inside the Administrative Tools control panel, or by running “net stop eventlog” with elevated privileges (hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER)
2.    Delete all of the files in C:\Windows\system32\winevt\Logs\
3.    Start the Event Log service with “net start eventlog” or through Services.

Comment: Ah, you have a GTX 1660 (we now know thanks to your edit). When diagnosing computer problems, making educated guesses is what intelligent people do. Do you have a USB stick with 32gb free?

Comment: @Gantendo I'm able to read and browse the Event-Viewer logs -with MMC\Event-Viewer just fine. The freezing of Event-Viewer (MMC) mainly happens when the 'search' function is used. That said, I'll try your suggestion and delete the existing logs then restart. However, this kind-of has me wondering: 1) if the logs are being damaged, what is triggering said damage and/or, 2) If its the SSD, why am I not seeing errors pointing to that media device as a possible 'general' problem (rhetorical)? e.g. SMART. If I don't have a USB, I'll order another; your turn ...

Comment: @Gantendo about the event and cbs logs, what is the best format 'and' method to post? If I use cloud I may need to delete to recover space, then the associated link is dead; there is no attachment function here.

Comment: 1) This is impossible to answer without guessing. Data corruption has many possible causes. 2) S.M.A.R.T isn't perfect https://serverfault.com/questions/519726/how-reliable-is-hdd-smart-data

Comment: If you have crash `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump` with the right dates, zip up a couple and post online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: @harrymc -- you may have missed my earlier postings about using cloud, as the links will break over time. In-turn future reference could possibly cripple or impede future readers full understanding. I was looking for a way to attach excerpts directly to this thread (internally); without hyper-links. 2) Thank you for reminding me about dmp files, that may help with the MMC\Event-Viewer issue. However, I'm still trying to get a line on the OS crashing; which is both --a) the priority, b) why I employed MMC\Event-Viewer, and c) how/when I encountered the MMC\Event-Viewer freeze/crashing.

Comment: @Gantendo, I've added **Addendum-01.** After reviewing, would you have anything further to add?